# R: removing the last elements of a vector

Tags: r, vector, element

How can I remove the last 100 elements of a zoo series?

I know the name[-element] notation 
but I can't get it work to substract a full section

Comment: thanks What I really need is a little bit more complicated.
I need to shift the series, removing some elements and adding other from the other side
but when I do c(rep(0,10),x[1:(length(x)-11)]) it's not zoo any more. cheers

Comment: @skan: What about accepting an answer to mark the question as resolved?

Answer (score 99):

I like using `head` for this because it's easier to type.  The other methods probably execute faster though... but I'm lazy and my computer is not. ;-)

```
x <- head(x,-100)
> head(1:102,-100)
[1] 1 2
```

Comment: This answer should be accepted.  It can be used without knowing the length of x in advance, which is advantageous if you are trying to selectively read data from a file.  From `?head`:  `n: If negative, [return] all but the n last/first number of elements of x.`

Comment: Worth noting there is also `tail()` which works identically but in reverse.

Answer (score 20):

Actually, there's a much faster way:

```
y <- x[1:(length(x)-1)]
```

Code show:

```
> microbenchmark( y <- head(x, -1), y <- x[-length(x)],y <- x[1:(length(x)-1)], times=10000)
 Unit: microseconds
                      expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq      max
          y <- head(x, -1) 71.399 76.4090 85.97572 78.9230 84.2775 2795.076
        y <- x[-length(x)] 53.623 55.5585 65.15008 56.5680 61.1585 2523.141
 y <- x[1:(length(x) - 1)] 25.722 28.2925 36.43029 29.1855 30.4010 2410.975
```

Comment: @yaleidu it would be better to use `x[seq_len(length(x)-1)]`, which works in the length-1 case too.

Answer (score 15):

I bet `length<-` is the most efficient way to trim a vector:

```
> x <- 1:10^5
> length(x)
[1] 100000
> length(x) <- 3
> x
[1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: Precious! almost as easy to type than `head()` but much simpler in everything else!

Answer (score 7):

Just use the numeric indices, ie

```
 N <- nrow(X)
 X <- X[1:(N-100-1),]
```

where you should need to ensure `N` is larger 100 etc

Answer (score 6):

if you're a one liner

```
x = x[1:(length(x) -101)]
```

Comment: With all your answers I've built almost what I need
coredata(zz2) <- c(rep(0,3),head(coredata(zz),-3))

Now I just need to use it inside a zoo series with several columns, modifying just one.

Answer (score 3):

Another one-liner for the sake of completeness:

```
x <- lag(x, 100)[-1:-100]
```