# remove the last element of a vector

Tags: r, vector

I need to remove the last number in a groups of vectors, i.e.:

```
v <- 1:3
v1 <- 4:8
```

should become:

```
v <- 1:2
v1 <- 4:7
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R: removing the last elements of a vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753687/r-removing-the-last-elements-of-a-vector)

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You can use negative offsets in `head` (or `tail`), so `head(x, -1)` removes the *last* element:

```
R> head( 1:4, -1)
[1] 1 2 3
R>
```

This also saves an additional call to `length()`.

*Edit:* As pointed out by Jason, this approach is actually not faster. Can't argue with empirics.  On my machine:

```
R> x <- rnorm(1000)
R> microbenchmark( y <- head(x, -1), y <- x[-length(x)], times=10000)
Unit: microseconds
                expr    min      lq median     uq     max
1   y <- head(x, -1) 29.412 31.0385 31.713 32.578 872.168
2 y <- x[-length(x)] 14.703 15.1150 15.565 15.955 706.880
R>
```

Comment: According to the source, `head` calls `length` twice, once for error checking and once for a call to `max` or `min`. Does `[` call it a total of three times? For some reason, I am having trouble finding the code that implements `[`.

Comment: +1 For the edit :) and, more importantly, reminding me that I can use `head` and `tail` this way.

Comment: @Dirk: I ran your code on my machine and using `-length()` is indeed faster. But if I increase the size of `x` to 10000, then `head` is actually about 2~3 times faster. There seems to be some dependency on the vector length but I don't have any explanation.

Comment: by symmetry, `tail(my_vector,-1)` can be used to remove the first element

Answer (score 60):

Use length to get the length of the object and - to remove the last one.

```
v[-length(v)]
```

A negative index in R extracts everything *but* the given indices.

Answer (score 11):

Dirk and Iselzer have already provided the answers. Dirk's is certainly the most straightforward, but on my system at least it is marginally slower, probably because vector subsetting with `[` and `length` checking is cheap (and according to the source, `head` does use `length`, twice actually):

```
> x <- rnorm(1000)
> system.time(replicate(50000, y <- head(x, -1)))
   user  system elapsed 
   3.69    0.56    4.25 
> system.time(replicate(50000, y <- x[-length(x)]))
   user  system elapsed 
  3.504   0.552   4.058
```

This pattern held up for larger vector lengths and more replications. YMMV. The legibility of `head` certainly out-weights the marginal performance improvement of `[` in most cases.

Comment: Yes, although legibility is a bit in the eye of the beholder.  I always have to spend an extra few milliseconds thinking about what `head` and `tail` really do with negative arguments ... whereas `x[-length(x)]`, while clunky, is idiomatic to my R-soaked brain.

Answer (score 4):

This is another option, which has not been suggested before. `NROW` treats your vector as a 1-column matrix.

```
v[-max(NROW(v))]#1 2
v1[-max(NROW(v1))]#4 5 6 7
```

Based on the discussion above, this is (slightly) faster then all the other methods suggested:

```
x <- rnorm(1000)
system.time(replicate(50000, y <- head(x, -1)))
user  system elapsed 
3.446   0.292   3.762
system.time(replicate(50000, y <- x[-length(x)]))
user  system elapsed 
2.131   0.326   2.472
system.time(replicate(50000, y <- x[-max(NROW(x))]))
user  system elapsed 
2.076   0.262   2.342
```

Comment: But why `max()`?

Comment: `system.time` is not completely reliable (neither is `microbenchmark`, but it at leasts gives you a better summary). The implementation of `NROW` returns length(x) if the object is a vector. The `max()` seems to be also completely arbitrary. So given call of NROW on a vector, it is identical to `length(x)` + few more function calls. Likely, GC was triggered (or triggered more often) during the second call, which reslted in longer `system.time`. But this should not be interpreted as a general rule.