# How would I sum elements of two vectors but exclude the last element

Tags: r, vector, sum, element

I want to sum all elements of vectors together. However, I am trying to exclude the last element of each vector. For example,

```
vector1 <- c(10,20,3000)
vector2 <- c(20,40,5000)

sum(vector1, vector2)
[1] 8090
```

But I would like to exclude the `3000` in `vector1` and the `5000` in `vector2` to output `[1] 90`. Also, this is just a reproducible example, my real vectors don't have the same consistent number of elements. Could this be done?

Comment: Relevant [remove the last element of a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114439/remove-the-last-element-of-a-vector)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually exclude the last component. 
One possibility is this:

```
sum(rev(vector1)[-1], rev(vector2)[-1])
```

`rev` reverses a vector, `[-1]` selects all but the first element (of the reversed vector).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `head` to remove the last element and `sum`

```
sum(head(vector1, -1), head(vector2, -1))
```

Or do

```
sum(vector1[-length(vector1)], vector2[-length(vector2)])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can deselect the last item of your vector before performing the sum:

```
vector1 <- c(10,20,3000)
vector2 <- c(20,40,5000)

sum(vector1[-length(vector1)], vector2[-length(vector2)])
```