# R omit last element in sequence

Tags: r, function, vector, subset, sequence

When we want a sequence in R, we use either construction:

```
> 1:5
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
> seq(1,5)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

this produces a sequence from start to stop (inclusive)
is there a way to generate a sequence from start to stop (exclusive)? like

```
[1] 1 2 3 4
```

Also, I don't want to use a workaround like a minus operator, like:

```
seq(1,5-1)
```

This is because I would like to have statements in my code that are elegant and concise. In my real world example the `start` and `stop` are not hardcoded integers but descriptive variable names. Using the `variable_name -1` construction just my script uglier and difficult to read for a reviewer.

PS: The difference between this question and the one at [remove the last element of a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114439/remove-the-last-element-of-a-vector) is that I am asking for sequence generation while the former focuses on removing the last element of a vector
Moreover the answers provided here are different and relevant to my problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [remove the last element of a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114439/remove-the-last-element-of-a-vector)

Comment: "Also, I don't want to use a workaround like a minus operator, like:". Please, clarify why not and which kind of solutions you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the following function

```
f <- function(start, stop, ...) {
  if(identical(start, stop)) {
    return(vector("integer", 0))
  }
  seq.int(from = start, to = stop - 1L, ...)
}
```

Test

```
f(1, 5)
# [1] 1 2 3 4

f(1, 1)
# integer(0)
```

Comment: @jochen Thanks for the heads-up. I made an edit

Answer (score 4):

One possible solution would be

```
head(1:5, -1)
# [1] 1 2 3 4
```

or you could define your own function

```
seq_last_exclusive <- function(x) return(x[-length(x)])
seq_last_exclusive(1:5)
# [1] 1 2 3 4
```